# Getting highest open level to go back only one step in off canvas mobile menu?

Tags: javascript

I've build a mobile offCanvas menu with *3 levels*.

**HTML markup:**

```
<div class="offcanvas-content-container">
  <a class="nav-item nav-link is-back-link navigation-offcanvas-link js-navigation-offcanvas-link" title="Back">
    <span itemprop="name">
            Back
        </span>
  </a>
  
  <div class="navigation-offcanvas-container js-navigation-offcanvas">
    <div class="navigation-offcanvas-overlay-content">

      <!-- FIRST LEVEL -->
      <ul class="list-unstyled navigation-offcanvas-list">
        <li class="navigation-offcanvas-list-item" data-first-trigger="id1" data-offcanvas-menu-level="level1">
          <div class="navigation-offcanvas-link nav-item">
            <span class="navigation-offcanvas-link-icon">Categories</span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <!-- SECOND LEVEL -->
      <ul class="navigation-offcanvas-entry list-unstyled navigation-offcanvas-list" data-first-offcanvas="id1"
          data-offcanvas-back="1">
        <li class="navigation-offcanvas-list-item" data-offcanvas-menu-level="level2"
            data-second-trigger="a515ae260223466f8e37471d279e6406">
          <div class="navigation-offcanvas-link nav-item">
            <span class="navigation-offcanvas-link-icon">Clothing</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        
        <li class="navigation-offcanvas-list-item" data-offcanvas-menu-level="level2"
            data-second-trigger="251448b91bc742de85643f5fccd89051">
          <div class="navigation-offcanvas-link nav-item">
            <span class="navigation-offcanvas-link-icon">Electronics</span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <!-- THIRD LEVEL -->
      <ul class="navigation-offcanvas-entry list-unstyled navigation-offcanvas-list"
          data-offcanvas-back="2" data-second-offcanvas="a515ae260223466f8e37471d279e6406">
        <li class="navigation-offcanvas-list-item">
          <a class="navigation-offcanvas-link nav-item" href="http://localhost:9998/Clothing/Women/" itemprop="url"
             title="Women">
            <span itemprop="name">Women</span>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="navigation-offcanvas-list-item">
          <a class="navigation-offcanvas-link nav-item" href="http://localhost:9998/Clothing/Men/" itemprop="url"
             title="Men">
            <span itemprop="name">Men</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To open next level a class `.is-open` is added to `.navigation-offcanvas-list`.

The **Problem**
is the back functionality. An eventlistener with `is-back-link` to remove any `is-open` class does not work because on level 3 it would jump back to level 1 instead to level 2, obviously.

My **Idea**
was to to get the highest open level and remove the class `.is-open` only from the corresponding classList.

```
        const offCanvasList = document.querySelectorAll(`.navigation-offcanvas-list.is-open[data-offcanvas-back]`);
        // console.log(offCanvasList)

        let highestOpenLevel = 0;
        offCanvasList.forEach((el) => {
            // console.log(el)
            highestOpenLevel = Math.max(highestOpenLevel, el.getAttribute('data-offcanvas-back'))
        });
        // console.log(highestOpenLevel)
        let openEl = document.querySelector(`.navigation-offcanvas-list.is-open[data-offcanvas-back='${highestOpenLevel}']`)
        // console.log(openEl)
        openEl.classList.remove("is-open")
```

This is not working at all. First problem is, it still jumps back to level 1 despite getting the correct `highestOpenLevel` when console logging. I even get the correct `openEl` in console log but when clicking the back button I get an console error: Uncaught TypeError: openEl is null

How can I make it going back only one step when clicking the back link?